# Derive deleted project from Xcode data or caches

Tags: objective-c, xcode, backup

I deleted my whole project folder (all .h and .m files and graphics, etc). Coming from Windows I thought that folders in MAC OS would merge, but they were replaced :-(

I don't have any snapshots. Is there any chance to retrieve any data? (reverse engineer any derived data or sth.?)

So far I could:

- rescue my graphics & sound from the .app file in the build folder.
- rescue my storyboard files from the "Autosave Information" folder (in ~/Library)

Comment: In the future, you should definitely investigate [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)!

Comment: Time Machine is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

How long ago did you delete them? If it was recently and you haven't emptied the trash yet, you might be able to find it there.

Just click the Trash icon on the dock, and see if the folder is in there. If it is, you can just drag it back into your project and everything should be fine.

If it is not there, however, it will be much difficult to recover it and you will have to find some program that searches for it and it may not be able to find it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing proper backups (such as Time Machine), or using source code control (subversion or git), or snapshots (which already stated were not being used), then you are out of luck unfortunately.

No source files end up in the built app or any of the derived data folders.

The trash, as Jsdodgers stated, is one last hope.

Please take this as an opportunity to get proper backups in place. Time Machine is such a simple thing to setup once you have an external drive setup. No more worries about lost files.